# How to show user location with a marker on react-google maps when page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, geolocation

```
import React from 'react';
import {GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker, InfoWindow} from '@react-google-maps/api';
import usePlacesAutocomplete, {getGeocode, getLatLng} from 'use-places-autocomplete';
import {Combobox, ComboboxInput, ComboboxPopover, ComboboxList, ComboboxOption} from "@reach/combobox";
import "@reach/combobox/styles.css";
import './App.css'; 

const libraries = ['places']
const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: '72vw',
  height: '100vh',
}
const options = {
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
}
const center = { lat: 55.70927, lng: 9.5357 }

export default function App() {
  const {isLoaded, loadError} = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyBRFI4qwdgva4fCSjZud-VLcXXywHYwAa4',
    libraries,
  })
  const [markers, setMarkers] = React.useState([])

  const onMapClick = React.useCallback((event) => {
      setMarkers(current => [
        ...current, 
        {
        lat: event.latLng.lat(),
        lng: event.latLng.lng(),
        time: new Date(),
      },
    ]);
   }, []);
   

   const mapRef = React.useRef();
   const onMapLoad = React.useCallback((map) => {
      mapRef.current = map;
   }, []);

 const panTo = React.useCallback(({lat, lng}) => {
   mapRef.current.panTo({lat, lng});
   mapRef.current.setZoom(14);
 }, []);

  if(loadError) return 'Error loading maps'
  if(!isLoaded) return 'Loading Maps'

  return (
  <div>
   
   <Locate panTo={panTo}/>
          <GoogleMap
             mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} 
             zoom={13}
             center={center}
             onClick={onMapClick}
             onLoad = {onMapLoad}
             options={options}
           >
             {markers.map((marker) => (
               <Marker 
               key={marker.time.toISOString()} 
               position = {{ 
                 lat: marker.lat,
                 lng: marker.lng
                 }} 
                icon = {{
                  url: '/food.png',
                  scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(20,20),
                  origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0,0),
                  anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(10,10)
                }} 
               />
             ))}
           </GoogleMap>
           <section id="sidebar">
              <h5 className="tc">Restaurant Review</h5>
           </section>
  </div>
  );
}


function Locate({panTo}) {
  return(
    <button className="locate" onClick={() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
         panTo({
           lat: position.coords.latitude,
           lng: position.coords.longitude,
         })
      }, () => null, options);
    }}>
     click
    </button>
  )
}
```

I would like to show venues in my area on Google Maps with a marker, but I also need to show the user location on page load. I created a function but is only working when the user clicks a button. I am new to React and JavaScript and don't know exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use useEffect() to trigger a function to run when the component is first rendered

```
useEffect (() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
         panTo({
           lat: position.coords.latitude,
           lng: position.coords.longitude,
         })
      }, () => null, options);
    }, [])
```

Comment: useEffect will guarantee loading of the wrapping React component, but not the MAP (child) component. So it wont work.